# What is wrong in this template definition?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <int N>
class myarray {
    typedef int Bitmap;
public:
    static Bitmap data[N];
};

template <int N> myarray<N>::Bitmap myarray<N>::data[N];
```

> error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before
>   ‘myarray’

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: Now for a stupid follow up question: Why not just delete the last line? Isn't that just a redundant second declaration?

Comment: Doh! I see now. Undefined references. It's the required *definition*, whereas the earlier line is just the *declaration*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `typename` before `myarray<N>::Bitmap` because it is a dependent type:

```
template <int N>
class myarray {
    typedef int Bitmap;
public:
    static Bitmap data[N];
};

   template <int N>
   typename myarray<N>::Bitmap myarray<N>::data[N];
// ^^^^^^^^
```